# C# two message boxes popping up - need to stop one

Tags: c#

Both message boxes run after each other when no buttons are checked when only the following should show:

```
{ MessageBox.Show("Incomplete order. Please review.", "Incomplete Order."); }
```

How do I prevent the following messagebox from running when no buttons are checked?

```
MessageBox.Show("You have ordered a " + pizzaChoice, "Order Confirmation.");
```

"Code"

```
private void ConfirmOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pizzaChoice = "";
    if (NeapolitanStyle.Checked == false & NEGreekStyle.Checked == false & ChicagoStyle.Checked == false & SmallPizza.Checked == false & MediumPizza.Checked == false & LargePizza.Checked == false)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Incomplete order. Please review.", "Incomplete Order."); 
    }
    if (SmallPizza.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + SmallPizza.Text + " "; 
    }
    if (MediumPizza.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + MediumPizza.Text + " "; 
    }
    if (LargePizza.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + LargePizza.Text + " "; 
    }
    if (NEGreekStyle.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + NEGreekStyle.Text + " pizza" + "\n";
    }
    if (ChicagoStyle.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + ChicagoStyle.Text + " pizza" + "\n";
    }
    if (NeapolitanStyle.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + NeapolitanStyle.Text + " pizza" + "\n"; 
    }
    if (VeryHotChilis.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + "& " + VeryHotChilis.Text + "." + "\n"; 
    }
    if (Onions.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + "& " + Onions.Text + "." + "\n"; 
    }
    if (Mushrooms.Checked)
    {
        pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + "& " + Mushrooms.Text + "."  + "\n"; 
    }
    MessageBox.Show("You have ordered a " + pizzaChoice, "Order Confirmation.");
}
```

Comment: `else if (SmallPizza.Checked)` <- add an `else` so that the other code only happens if the order is not incomplete.

Comment: As you might have noticed this type of coding is not scalable at all. You should explore databinding in Winforms so that you can avoid writing this messy business logic.

Comment: Or simply add `return;` after first `MessageBox`. `{ MessageBox.Show("Incomplete order. Please review.", "Incomplete Order."); return; }`.

Comment: @Cory agreed.  Remember OP, CTRL + K + D will format your code nicely in VIsual Studio.  It helps when posting for others to read.

Answer (score 1):

You will go a long way if you changed

```
 if (SmallPizza.Checked)
```

to

```
 else if (SmallPizza.Checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the function after the first error message appears. just place a `return;` after the messagebox

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation to the else if suggestions by Frank Pytel. Rather than changing subsequent if's to else if's it needs to be an if else for the first validation check then the series of if statements within the else block as follows..

```
private void ConfirmOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pizzaChoice = "";
    if (NeapolitanStyle.Checked == false & NEGreekStyle.Checked == false & ChicagoStyle.Checked == false & SmallPizza.Checked == false & MediumPizza.Checked == false & LargePizza.Checked == false)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Incomplete order. Please review.", "Incomplete Order."); 
    }
    else {
        if (SmallPizza.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + SmallPizza.Text + " "; 
        }
        if (MediumPizza.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + MediumPizza.Text + " "; 
        }
        if (LargePizza.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + LargePizza.Text + " "; 
        }
        if (NEGreekStyle.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + NEGreekStyle.Text + " pizza" + "\n";
        }
        if (ChicagoStyle.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + ChicagoStyle.Text + " pizza" + "\n";
        }
        if (NeapolitanStyle.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + NeapolitanStyle.Text + " pizza" + "\n"; 
        }
        if (VeryHotChilis.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + "& " + VeryHotChilis.Text + "." + "\n"; 
        }
        if (Onions.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + "& " + Onions.Text + "." + "\n"; 
        }
        if (Mushrooms.Checked)
        {
            pizzaChoice = pizzaChoice + "& " + Mushrooms.Text + "."  + "\n"; 
        }
        MessageBox.Show("You have ordered a " + pizzaChoice, "Order Confirmation.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can do like

```
if (MessageBox.Show("First MessageBox", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {

          MessageBox.Show("Second messageBox", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay entering return; did the trick. I tried putting the 'else if' in but both message boxes were still popping up.

Thanks guys. Most appreciated.